# generic of generic

Tags: c#, generics

I've a generic base class where generic type is class and other related inherited class:

```
public class BaseClass<T> where T : class 
{
   virtual void DoWork(){..}
   virtual void DoAnotherWork(){..}
}

public class SomeInherit<Person> : BaseClass<Person>
{
   //...
}

public class OtherInherit<Car> : BaseClass<Car>
{
   // override something..
}
```

Then, I've a BaseClassManager which should be able to load some BaseClass inherited by some co-worker via reflection:

```
public class BaseClassManager
{
   public BaseClass<TItem> LoadBaseClass<T>() where T : BaseClass<???>
   {
      //  how can create an instance of T?
      //  TItem : class
      //  T : BaseClass
      //  -------------> in reality, it should be: T<TItem> (just as BaseClass<Person>)
   }
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish that..?

Comment: Isn't "public BaseClass<T> LoadBaseClass<T> where T: class" is what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define a second type parameter for `where T : BaseClass<???>`.
You can use [the `new()` constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to allow the method to create instances of a generic type.

```
public TBaseClass LoadBaseClass<TBaseClass, TItem>()
    where TBaseClass : BaseClass<TItem>, new()
    where TItem : class
{
    return new TBaseClass();
}
```

*Usage:*

```
SomeInherit<Foo> result = LoadBaseClass<SomeInherit<Foo>, Foo>();
```